# Why does query with UDF fail with "Task not serializable" exception?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, serialization, apache-spark-sql

I have created a UDF and I am trying to apply it on the result of the coalesce inside a join.
Ideally I would like to do this during a join:

```
def foo(value: Double): Double = {
    value / 100
}

val foo = udf(foo _)

df.join(.....)
  .withColumn("value",foo(coalesce(new Column("valueA"), new Column("valueB"))))
```

But I am getting the exception `Task not serializable`. 
Is there a way to work around that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use lambda function to make it serializable. This example works fine.

```
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.coalesce
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
val central: DataFrame = Seq(
  (1,  Some(2014)),
  (2,  null)
).toDF("key", "year1")

val other1: DataFrame = Seq(
  (1,  2016),
  (2,  2015)
).toDF("key", "year2")
def fooUDF = udf{v: Double => v/100}

val result = central.join(other1, Seq("key"))
  .withColumn("value",fooUDF(coalesce(col("year1"), col("year2"))))
```

Answer (score 0):

> But I am getting the exception `Task not serializable`.

The reason for the infamous "Task not serializable" exception is that `def foo(value: Double): Double` is a part of an unserializable owning object (perhaps with `SparkSession` that indirectly references an unserializable `SparkContext`).

A solution is to define the method as part of a "standalone" object that has no references to unserializable values.

> Is there a way to work around that?

See the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48005068/1305344) by @firas.